# Is there a way to load specific features from jQuery in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

As I can see, loading jQuery every time I load a site is pretty slow. i.e.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Site Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJS.js"></script>
```

Compared to downloading jQuery to my local file system and import it locally. i.e.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-someversion.min.js"></script>
<!-- Site Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJS.js"></script>
```

Obviously depends on my internet's speed at the time of loading the script.

I was wondering if there is a jQuery API of some sort that would allow me to "lazy load" it(jQuery) using HTML script tag. What I mean with lazy loading jQuery is: loading only the specific feature(s) I'm going to use, i.e.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js/events"></script>
<!-- Site Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJS.js"></script>
```

Changed the source: *< script .... src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js/**events**"/ >*

I know that I can look up for the jQuery code of that specific feature and load it myself when needed, but **I do NOT want to copy the features into my local file system** every time jQuery has an update or whatever. If you are still not getting where I'm going, what I want is to have a way in which I know that the features are UP TO DATE and SUPPORTED (by jQuery) so later bug-fixes/improvements/changes/additions/cross-browser-support to jQuery are "automagically" implemented in my site.

Comment: it may be "slow", but it's only the *first* time it's slow. also, if you go with an actual version (instead of always fetching latest) you're going to have even better caching as the timeout isn't set to expire as soon. (For obvious reasons, it's the "latest" version and therefore cannot be cached too long).

Comment: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` is *only* 32.5KB after HTTP compression *and* it is *very cacheable*. I think that perhaps, there are other performance issues to eliminate first.

Comment: And than when a BUG fix breaks your production code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you will use a cdn path, then it will not redownload the file if it has been cached previously. It increases the chance that there will be a cache-hit.
(As more sites follow this practice, more users already have the file ready.)

Answer (score 2):

You're *always* going to be slower fetching `jquery-latest` vs `jquery-version`--the server enforces it. For example:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

[image: jquery-latest headers]

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

[image]

Note that there is now a *very* future dated `Expires` header sent. That means that once the first page is loaded, the browser is going to cache this version for a very long time making subsequent page calls have [almost] no latency.

By staying with the latest, however, you're forcing the browser to fetch this file for *every page load*. Of course that's going to add latency.

> what I want is to have a way in which I know that the features are UP TO DATE and SUPPORTED (by jQuery) so later bug-fixes/improvements/changes/additions/cross-browser-support to jQuery are "automagically" implemented in my site.

Except when you write something that uses [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/), [`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) or [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) then wonder why it's no longer working.

There's something to be said for spending the few minutes and updating your JS files (especially if it means your site worked yesterday and doesn't today and you don't know why).

Comment: Even "latest" release doesn't change very fast though .. and an update to the resource URL is sufficient (with the new resource also having a long cache period, assuming the server has been configured correctly). Of course using the CDN does help global caching.

Comment: @user2864740: It's not really about the file itself, it's how the browsers manage caching. Moreover, you keep grabbing latest and you're going to run in to issue (eventually) with something that went from active to deprecated to removed. (*cough* `$.browser` or `$().live`)

Comment: Oh, I'm not in favor of "automatic updates" (over more than point releases) by any means.

Comment: Thank you @BradChristie ! It is not entirely what I'm looking for, but you did help me understand a lot more of what it is happening.

Comment: @Camou i realize that, but you're worried about versioning now? You're going to have a heck of a time versioning jQuery if you break it in to components. Moreover, you're trying to optimize something that _really_ isn't the worst of the latency. jQuery, in the scheme of things, isn't going to cripple a website due to its size.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own build of jQuery but you will have to host it yourself.

Follow the ["How to build your own jQuery" guide](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#readme) for instructions:

> Special builds can be created that exclude subsets of jQuery functionality. This allows for smaller custom builds when the builder is certain that those parts of jQuery are not being used. For example, an app that only used JSONP for $.ajax() and did not need to calculate offsets or positions of elements could exclude the offset and ajax/xhr modules.

Comment: Cool read, never knew that. Anyway, while I might do this for a very constrained system where I would *never* need module X, I would not do it to break up jQuery into "dynamically loadable" modules - that just seems like a nightmare (and then having to try and stitch everything back together).

Comment: Could you give a small example?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say so! jQuery's size is only 32KB!

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

You will spent **much more** time loading multiple files than one. Furthermore, it will be a good idea to merge all you JS and CSS files into one JS and one CSS file.

Comment: Nit: It's ~90KB, it goes down to ~32KB with HTTP compression.

Comment: So what? :-) P.S. Not HTTP compression, but gzip ;-)